Approximation a piecewise affine function with sigmoid function
I am dealing with the following piecewise affine function:
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if } x \in [0,1] \\
x - 1, & \text{if } x \in [1,2] \\
1, & \text{if } x \in [2,3] \\
\end{cases}
$$
I want to use the sigmoid (smooth) function
$$
f_{k}(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-k(x-3/2)}}
$$
to approximate the non-smooth function ( f ). However, I do not know how to parametrize it. more precisely, how can I generate a smooth function $f_k$ if I consider another function $f$ with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ instead of $1,2$ and $3$?
